# $C_p$ of ideal gas from entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm trying to derive $C_p$ from entropy of ideal gas:

[image]

But I'm getting an extra $T$ that's messing with my calculation. Do you know where the problem might be?

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have started with a wrong definition. The heat capacity is defined as

$${C_X} = T{\left( {\frac{{\partial S}}{{\partial T}}} \right)_X},$$

where $X=V$ or $P$. I think you know the rest.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that, Thank you

Comment: @OndraJanoška - I make mistakes in my calculations every day and every day! This is normal.